# Is it possible to query a users role in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am looking to write a command that only a specific role can access and was wondering if it was possible to query for a role

What I tried doing was something like this

```
if (!message.member.role("CEO")) return;
```

I received an error stating that .role was not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.member.role()` is not a valid property of `GuildMember`, but, `message.member.roles()` is, it is a `Collection`.

You should start by getting the `Role` object.

```
// Get the role by ID
let myRole = message.guild.roles.get("264410914592129025");

// Get role by name
let myRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Admin");
```

To check if they have a role, use `.has()` method of `Collection`.

```
message.member.roles.has(myRole)
message.member.roles.has("543965345763464434") // You can use the role ID directly because the roles are mapped by their ID.
```

To check if they have one of many roles:

```
if (message.member.roles.some(role => ["Role1", "Role2"].includes(role.name))) {
   // They have either Role1 or Role2.
}
```